# Can I use parry attacks of opportunity with Swashbuckler's Parry and Riposte?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, optimization, class-feature

I am playing pathfinder, I have a level 5 Swashbuckler. Among his feats he has combat reflexes, which increases the number of attacks of opportunity that he can use each round.

The swashbuckler deed:

> *Opportune Parry and Riposte (Ex)*:
>   At 1st level, when an opponent makes a melee attack against the swashbuckler, she can spend 1 panache point and expend a use of an attack of opportunity to attempt to parry that attack. The swashbuckler makes an attack roll as if she were making an attack of opportunity; for each size category the attacking creature is larger than the swashbuckler, the swashbuckler takes a –2 penalty on this roll. If her result is greater than the attacking creature’s result, the creature’s attack automatically misses. The swashbuckler must declare the use of this ability after the creature’s attack is announced, but before its attack roll is made. Upon performing a successful parry and if she has at least 1 panache point, the swashbuckler can as an immediate action make an attack against the creature whose attack she parried, provided that creature is within her reach. This deed’s cost cannot be reduced by any ability or effect that reduces the number of panache points a deed costs.

My question is: If I move through a threatened square and provoke an attack of opportunity, would I be able to parry that attack? If so would I be able to continually move in and out of threatened squares, until I either run out of movement, attacks of opportunity, or Panache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opportune Parry and Riposte requires an immediate action to make an attack:

> Upon performing a successful parry and if she has at least 1 panache point, the swashbuckler can **as an immediate action** make an attack against the creature whose attack she parried, provided that creature is within her reach.

Yes, you can use it against attacks of opportunity, but you can only riposte once per round since you only get one immediate action per round regardless of the number of attacks of opportunity you could take. You could still parry a, presumably, greater number of attacks but that wouldn't do much beyond helping your less-nimble allies.

In your particular example, however, you'll have to get creative if you want to provoke more than one attack from your opponent. You only [provoke a single attack of opportunity](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/combat.html#attacks-of-opportunity) from your opponent due to movement because

> Moving out of more than one square threatened by the same opponent in the same round doesn't count as more than one opportunity for that opponent.

Comment: It may be worth noting that if they Riposted an attack since their last round, they've used their Swift Action and cannot Riposte during their turn. "[effectively, using an immediate action before your turn is equivalent to using your swift action for the coming turn](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Immediate-Actions)"

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, sort of, and no.**

**Yes:** Spending 1 panache to parry is not an action. When the enemy gets their attack of opportunity, if it's a melee attack, then that meets the requirements for this deed. As long as you have enough of your own attacks of opportunity, you can spend 1 panache perform the parry.

**Sort of:** If you have multiple opponents, then moving through their threatened squares will provoke one [attack of opportunity](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Attacks-of-Opportunity) from each of them. Whenever one of them makes their attack of opportunity, you can spend 1 panache and try to parry.

**No:** You only get one [immediate action or swift action](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Immediate-Actions) per round. Since riposte (your counter-attack) requires an immediate action, you can only perform one of them until your turn on the following round.